# Java Enum behavior

Tags: java, enums

We have the following enumeration:

```
public enum ComponentTypes {

    PDIFF(301),
    TDIFF(302),
    TADJ(303);

    private long componentTypeId;

    private ComponentTypes(long componentTypeId){
        this.componentTypeId = componentTypeId;
    }

    public Long getId(){
        return this.componentTypeId;
    }
}
```

In one of our tests setup we do `c.setComponentTypeId(ComponentTypes.TADJ.getId())` but when `c.getComponentTypeId()` is invoked in the test it throws `NullPointerException`, yet `c.setComponentTypeId(303L)` works as expected. What am I missing with use of the enum to set the value?

**EDIT**

Looks like @Tom was straight on with the long/Long inconsistency. Now that `getId()` returns `long` not `Long` it works as expected.

**EDIT**

Looks like what I said earlier was wrong **autoboxing does work there as expected** is no issue after I refreshed the system jvm etc -- which doesn't make any sense to me!

Comment: Erm, you seem to be showing is the wrong code. Where is the code for `[gs]etComponentTypeId`?

Comment: (Note also that in one case you are using `long` and the other `Long`.)

Comment: @Tom `[gs]etComponentTypeId` is a pojo construct on a Long field

Comment: @Tom thanks for the hint but I don't know how to give you credit for it so I raised you +1 for your comment

Comment: Can someone explain why this is - why is the autoboxing failing?  Something tells me that this is related to what c looks like.

Comment: Are you sure that `c` is not null ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what type "c" is, but I suspect its setter is not doing what you think it is -- the NullPointerException is an indication of auto-unboxing gone wrong. You enum itself doesn't appear to have an issue, although returning a `Long` when the member is `long` is a code smell.

Actually, calling `c.setComponentTypeId()` with the enum's ID is another code smell. Why aren't you using the enum itself, with `c.setComponentType()`? The way you're doing it pretty much loses you all the value of enums.

Comment: In this case we specifically want the `id` 303 not the constant `TADJ`.

Answer (score 0):

You say in the test you call setComponentId, but you have not included the source for this method. Can you paste this, and also show how the 'c' object in the test is created?

Tom, if they are using a version of recent java supporting autoboxing surely long/Long won't matter?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you initializing c?  I suspect this is the issue and that the NullPointerException you're receiving is actually coming from the setComponentTypeId call not the getter.

Using your code for the enum (with no modifications) I ran the following:

```
ComponentTypes c = ComponentTypes.PDIFF;
c.setComponentTypeId(ComponentTypes.TADJ.getId());
System.out.println(c.getComponentTypeId());

c.setComponentTypeId(303L);
System.out.println(c.getComponentTypeId());
```

My Output:

> 303
>
> 303

However; If c is not initialized properly, you get a NullPointerException when you attempt to call c.setComponentTypeId for the first time.